# XSLT jquery classname and ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xslt, classname

So I have an XSLT form that gets data from an XML form and display it to me.I want to get the value of the elements via class name but it keeps returning undefined. Here is a snippet of the XSLTcode

```
<!-- generic input template -->
<xsl:template match="DataField" priority="0">
<td colspan="{DisplayOptions/@ColSpan}" location="{DisplayOptions/@Column}">
  <xsl:value-of select="FieldOptions/@DisplayName"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="{@ControlType}" name="{@Name}" onchange="textBlur(event)" />

  <xsl:apply-templates select="SubDataFields"/>
</td>

</xsl:template>
```

The two ways that I have tried is jquery and using document

```
function textBlur(e) {
//this gives me the value and works
var personInfo = e.target.value;
var personField = e.target.name;

//these two return undefined
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("personField");
console.log($(elements).val());

console.log($("."+personField).val());
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? personField is the name of the element that I want. Since the XSLT generate the class name for me. So what I did was use the event to get the element's name and value to confirm that I am using the right name and is getting a value, then I try to get the value of the elements again using jquery and the name.

Comment: I do not understand  what you try to show here. You try to get elements by class personField, but your xslt example does not generate  this class. What do I miss here?

Comment: @hr_117 personField is the name of the element that I want. Since the XSLT generate the class name for me. So what I did was use the event to get the element's name and value to confirm that I am using the right name, then I try to get the value of the elements again using jquery and the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to grab the value whenever any of the text in any of the input boxes changes.  In the textBlur function, you are passing the "event" object, so event.target is already the element you want to find.

However, if you want to do it by class name, it seems you don't have a class name set on the input tag yet.  You should likely change this to:

```
<input class="personField" type="{@ControlType}" name="{@Name}" onchange="textBlur(event)" />
```

Also, your jQuery code was using the value of the name attribute of the field (i.e. personField = e.target.name), rather than a fixed string name for the class name.  In other words, I think you want to use this:

```
console.log($(".personField").val());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: HAHAHA omg. I was using name and thinking it was class name and therefore was treating it that way. Stupidest brain fart ever.I would have to use the [jquery attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) Thnx.